# How can I move one specific file from an <input type=file multiple> to inside a specific form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

`<input type=file multiple>` inputs many files and I want to associate them to separate forms!

```
<label for="hiddenInput" class="btn btnPrimary mr-2">
    Browse
    <input type="file" id="hiddenInput" class="js-file-input" multiple>
</label>


<form id="form" action="uploadOneImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label><b>Tags</b> (optional)</label>
    <input name="tags" type="text" name="tags" class="tags">
    <label><b>Location</b> (optional)</label>
    <input name="location" type="text" name="location" class="location">
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btnPrimary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this file upload? I'm not sure what you mean by *"associate them to separate forms"*

Comment: There is a single input type=file that inputs multiple files. I want each file to go to a separate form ( so that I can get different tags or locations for each file) and get submitted by their submit button.

Comment: I have edited the code. You can have another look!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood you want to carry files to another `<input type="file" multiple>`  which is under another form

add
`<input type="file" id="otherInput" style="display:none" multiple/>` under `#form`

in javascript:

```
document.querySelector('#hiddenInput').addEventListener('input', () => {
  const dt = new DataTransfer();
  const files = document.querySelector('#hiddenInput').files;

  for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    const file = files[i];
    dt.items.add(file);
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#otherInput').files = dt.files;
})
```